# How can I create 8-bit audio files?

Tags: recording, quality

I have a client that wants 8-bit WAV files with music for telephone IVR recordings. I work in Adobe Audition and one time by some fluke the recording did not sound too bad. I was not able to reproduce this. I've found that not shortening (remixing for length) the music helps a bit.

I wonder if you could point me in the right direction in how to generate 8-bit WAV files. Perhaps I should try Audacity or some other DAW.

I am just a VO so not too technical. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Audacity will happily output 8 bit wave files. Choose export > other uncompressed then MS wav and 8 bit unsigned.

Comment: I've worked on a similar project and Audacity was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In order to output 8-bit files from 16, you need to add dither. You can get amazing results with dither. Even 3 or 4 bit files can sound good with enough dither.

Dither is your friend.

You need Dither.

Dither is noise. usually shaped.

Dither is good.

Add Dither.